# How to migrate Windows server 2003 32 Bit Active Directory to WIndows server 2019 64 bit

Tags: active-directory

I want to Migrate Server 2003 32-Bit Active Directory to Windows server 2019 64-Bit.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Given the following documented requirements for installing a 2019 Domain Controller in an environment:

- Domain Functional Level minimum of 2008
- DFSR-based SYSVOL Replication

The basic process would be:

- Install at least one (likely two) Domain Controller(s) running either 2008, 2008 R2, or 2012.  If I recall correctly, a DC running 2012 R2 will not work with a Server 2003 DC
- [**Transfer** the FSMO roles to one of the new DCs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/move-addirectoryserveroperationmasterrole)
- Decomission all 2003 DCs
- [Raise the Domain Functional Level to 2008 (or which ever is most appropriate for your new DCs OS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753104(v=ws.11))
- [Migrate SYSVOL replication from FRS to DFSR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-replication/migrate-sysvol-to-dfsr)
- Install at least two new Domain Controller running 2019
- [**Transfer** the FSMO roles to one of the new 2019 DCs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/move-addirectoryserveroperationmasterrole)
- Decomission the 2008/2008 R2/2012 DC
- (Optionally) [Raise the Domain Functional Level to 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753104(v=ws.11))
- (Optionally, unreleated, but recommended) [Enable the Active Directory Recycle Bin](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/enable-adoptionalfeature)

---

Please keep in mind that there can be significant domain member incompatibilties with the default security posture of Server 2019 Domain Controllers.  Perform a review of your environment to identify any older, out-of-support OSes running on domain members that may be unable to communicate or authenticate with modern OSes in their default configuration.

Comment: Your 2nd, 3rd, and 5th links are 404'ing.

Comment: Very wierd; thanks for the heads-up.  I've updated the links.